# Does Elixir/Erlang Random/Rand Seed need to be called on each process?

Tags: random, erlang, elixir, seed

From Hashrockets blog post on "[The Adventures of Generating Random Numbers in Erlang and Elixir](https://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/the-adventures-of-generating-random-numbers-in-erlang-and-elixir)" Dorian Karter mentions that opening and closing `erl` sessions allows him to reproduce the same output from the PRNG `random:uniform().`.

> Turns out random uses the same seed by default for every VM instance.

E.G:

**Session one**

```erl
1> random:uniform().
0.4435846174457203
```

**Session two**

```erl
1> random:uniform().
0.4435846174457203
```

I can't seem to find in documentation, or my searches across the net if calling the seed methods will apply to the whole VM, or to the process that calls the seed method only.

The question:
In Elixir, would you need to call the seed (for both `random` or `rand`) function per erlang process? Or does one call ~somewhere~ apply across the entire Erlang runtime?

Answer (score 6):

The `rand` module supersedes the `random` module:

> The improved rand module is to be used instead of this module.

However with the `rand` module:

> If a process calls uniform/0, uniform/1 or uniform_real/0 without setting a seed first, seed/1 is called automatically with the default algorithm and creates a non-constant seed.

So you'll have different results after VM restart with `rand:uniform/0`.

However if you use randomness for cryptography purpose, then you should use [`crypto:strong_rand_bytes/1`](https://erlang.org/doc/man/crypto.html#strong_rand_bytes-1).

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation at https://erlang.org/doc/man/random.html:

> Seeds random number generation ... in the *process dictionary* and returns the old state.

(emphasis mine)

So, yes, the `random` module requires each process be seeded individually.